# Using Jest, how to trigger a breakpoint only when a test case fails?

Tags: javascript, debugging, jestjs, webstorm

Given a test case similar to this one:

```
test(“test”, () => {
    [1, 2, ..., 1000000].map(value => {
        expect(() => foo(value)).toThrow();
    });
})
```

is there a simple way to set a breakpoint (e.g. on line 3) that will only be triggered if the expect statement fails?

In other words, if one of the values somewhere in the middle of a big array is causing the test to fail, while most of the values do not trigger the exceptional condition, is there some way to set a breakpoint that will be skipped if the test passes but break if the test fails?

That would make it a lot easier to figure out why the test is failing for that value.

I am using WebStorm, so I would be satisfied with an answer for how to do it with Chrome/node, with code, or with WebStorm.

Comment: did you try using [conditional breakpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint-properties)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the values at compile time then you can use [`test.each`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testeachtable-name-fn-timeout) to create unique tests for each value which lets you see clearly which value is failing:

```
const tests = [[6], [7], [8]];

test.each(tests)(
  '%i should be even',
  v => {
    expect(v % 2).toBe(0);
  }
)
```

...which reports that two tests pass (6 and 8) and fails on 7 with a descriptive message:

```
● 7 should be even

expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: 0
Received: 1

  4 |   '%i should be even',
  5 |   v => {
> 6 |     expect(v % 2).toBe(0);
    |                   ^
  7 |   }
  8 | )

  at toBe (src/code.test.js:6:19)
```

---

If the test data isn't available until runtime and the assertion is a simple one, then you can just set a conditional breakpoint on the `expect` line:

```
const generateData = count => {
  const data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    data.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  }
  return data;
}

test('all values are even', () => {
  generateData(1000).map(v => {
    expect(v % 2).toBe(0);  // <= set breakpoint for v % 2 !== 0
  });
})
```

---

If the test data isn't available until runtime and it would be difficult to set a conditional breakpoint then you can wrap the `expect` in a `try / catch` and put a breakpoint in the `catch`:

```
const generateData = count => {
  const data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    data.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  }
  return data;
}

test('all values are even', () => {
  generateData(1000).map(v => {
    try {
      expect(v % 2).toBe(0);
    }
    catch (err) {
      throw err;  // <= set your breakpoint here
    }
  });
})
```

`expect` statements work by throwing an `Error` if the assertion fails, so this approach simply catches and re-throws the `Error` but gives you a place to set a breakpoint that will get triggered for the failing `expect`.